Getting 'E11000 duplicate key error' from MongoDB
I'm trying to populate a MongoDB collection using Python and the PyMongo package. I have >300,000 documents to insert, and I got the aforementioned error after 200,000+ inserts.
For context, I am trying to build a word guessing game and am ranking the words.
Here is the code chunk that I used:
def post_rankings(client, db, collection, ranked_words): 
    try:
        ## Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
        client.admin.command('ping')
        print('Pinged! Successfully connected to MongoDB!')
        
        ## Establish connection to relevant collection
        db = client.get_database(db)
        collection = db.get_collection(collection)

        print(f'Adding {len(ranked_words)} ranked words to database...')
        for idx in range(len(ranked_words)):
            doc = {
                'text': ranked_words[idx], 
                'rank': idx + 1 ## Rankings start from 1
            }

            ## Add rankings to database
            _ = collection.insert_one(doc)

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error adding rankings to database: ', e)

and here is the output from the except block:
Error adding rankings to database:  E11000 duplicate key error collection: puzzles.temp_puzzle_30-07-2024 index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('66a8cc4cfb818aa00ab9aab4') }, full error: {'index': 0, 'code': 11000, 'errmsg': "E11000 duplicate key error collection: puzzles.temp_puzzle_30-07-2024 index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('66a8cc4cfb818aa00ab9aab4') }", 'keyPattern': {'_id': 1}, 'keyValue': {'_id': ObjectId('66a8cc4cfb818aa00ab9aab4')}}
I looked into the error and it seems that it happens when you try to insert a document with an id that is already present in the collection. However, since I am not specifying the object id, MongoDB should automatically create unique ids whenever a document is added.
I queried for the object id in the error message, and turns out it belongs to the last inserted document:

So it looks like MongoDB is trying to reuse the previous id? That's my guess but it doesn't really make sense to me, especially since I did something similar (inserting the same number of documents) in another collection just before this, and it went fine.
Similar posts also suggest maybe it has something to do with index or default values, but I don't use any of those in my case.
For now, I'll drop the collection and re-run the code to see if I get the same error.
